# Counting SQL results aswell as outputting the result data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, select, count

What i try to do is, counting my rows in this SQL statement, as well as want to retrieve the data into the `Repeater`. This is `ASP.NET` / `C#`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'numbersOfOrdres' 
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.customer_id = orders.order_customer_id
```

Doesn't seems to work, i'll keep getting the error `"Does not contain 'THEN MY FIELD NAME'` in the Repeater.

EDIT:
Repeater code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="customerOrdersRepeater" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Customer name</b></td><td><b>Customer adresse</b></td><td>Numbers of orders</td>
    </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%# Eval("customer_name") %></td><td><%# Eval("customer_adresse") %></td><td><%# Eval("numbersOfOrdres") %></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: Just in case. Does your field name is correct? customer_adresse

Comment: Yes it is, just double checked :D

Comment: Did you run your script on DB? Does it work? Could you provide full error you get?

Comment: Try to remove 'as' if it is SQL Server

Comment: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'customer_name'.

Comment: I only gets the output of my numbersOfOrdre field. I'd never gets the information from my tables other rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to aggregate your results using `GROUP BY`. It looks like you want a row per unique customer/customer address. So assuming these are held in `customers.name` and `customers.adresse` your query would be

```
SELECT customers.name AS customer_name, customers.adresse AS customer_adresse, 
    COUNT(*) AS 'numbersOfOrdres' 
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.customer_id = orders.order_customer_id
GROUP BY customers.name, customers.adresse
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do I think you need to use a group by.

This is what I think you want to see

```
Customer 1, customer_1_address, 3
Customer 2, customer_2_address, 1
Customer 3, customer_3_address, 5
```

assuming 3 customers, with 3, 1 and 5 orders respectively.

If so, a group by will likely get what you want, ie

```
select 
  customer_name,
  customer_address,
  count(*)
from
  customers
join
  orders
on customers.cust_id = orders.cust_id
group by customer_name, customer_address
```

There may be more efficient ways of stating the group by, ie grouping on the cust_id in a su query then joining on that to get the customer names and addresses. Assuming the above select works for you though I'll leave further improvements to yourself.

Comment: That worked also, but Smirkin answered the same just a moment ago :D Thanks tho!